# Record-triggered flow not working

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I need the clarification for the below work of record triggered flow.

The actual requirement is need to **add a new checkbox field in a case object and that checkbox field should only checked whenever the attachment is added in case record**. Otherwise the checkbox should unchecked.( If attachment presents , the checkbox = true. If attachment not presents , the checkbox = false)

[image]

I tried to achieve this work with both Record-Triggered flow and trigger. But its not work. Am not clear, where I did the mistake here. Anyone please assist me resolve this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also I tried with the trigger , But that also not works on records.

**New trigger with attachment object, but this too not working.**

trigger UpdateAttachmentExists on Attachment (after insert,after update, after delete)

{

```
Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();

// Collect Case IDs from Attachments
if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Attachment att : Trigger.new){
        caseIds.add(att.ParentId);
    }
}
else if(Trigger.isDelete){
    for(Attachment att : Trigger.old){
        caseIds.add(att.ParentId);
    }
}

// Update the Attachment Exists checkbox on Case records
for(Case cse : [SELECT Id, Attachment_Exists__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds]){
    Boolean hasAttachments = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :cse.Id] > 0;
    cse.Attachment_Exists__c = hasAttachments;
    casesToUpdate.add(cse);
}

update casesToUpdate;
```

}**

Comment: so -- adding an attachment to a Case does not cause DML on the Case so a record-triggered flow or trigger on Case will never execute. You need to do the logic in a  on Attachment (or if using Files, on ContentDocumentLink)

Comment: @cropredy: Thank you ! so I need to create logic in same trigger or I need to use separate apex class to execute this? Is not possible in record triggered flow right?

Comment: when something is uploaded, are you using the `Attachment` object or (the more modern) Files?  Files uses `ContentVersion/ContentDocument/ContentDocumentLink` objects

Comment: Yes, am using only the Attachment object for any uploads.

Comment: see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/200718/2602) - either custom trigger or DLRS

Comment: For the purpose of using attachment object. I have tried trigger also with attachment object. But that was not triggered in case records. That's the reason , am hanging on my work. I upload my new trigger code on above. Please check and correct me if I dis any wrong .

Comment: you need to write the trigger on Attachment - not on Case.  Then update a field on Case with count of attachments.  DLRS can do this for you via config only

Comment: your trigger does soql inside a for loop - not good practice - switch to DLRS and save the count of attachments in Case; then your has attachments field can be a formula field

Comment: @cropredy: Yes, I write the trigger on attachment object too and update field on case with the count of attachments. But its not works in case records. Its not triggering, Please review my trigger on bottom of my question and advise.